# Basic BeautifulSoup Wikipedia scrape

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a very basic, and short, basic unordered list `<ul>` off of Wikipedia. My end goal is to put it into a `DataFrame`.
My question is, where do I go from here?

```
In [28]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

         import urllib2

         import requests

         from pandas import Series,DataFrame

In [29]: url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Pro_Grid_League"

In [31]: result = requests.get(url)

In [32]: c = result.content

In [33]: soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
```

I cant seem to find any answers on this StackOverflow, so I would appreciate any advice anyone could give me.
This is the specific list I'm looking for:

```
Active teams[edit]
Baltimore Anthem (2015–present)
Boston Iron (2014–present)
DC Brawlers (2014–present)
Los Angeles Reign (2014–present)
Miami Surge (2014–present)
New York Rhinos (2014–present)
Phoenix Rise (2014–present)
San Francisco Fire (2014–present)
```

Comment: thx dear Spencer - and also George - this is python 2 based. I need to rewrite it to version3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you'll want to find the correct part of the page. You can do this by finding the heading with `id="Active_teams_at_league_closing"` and then finding the next `<ul>` element from there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Pro_Grid_League"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

heading = soup.find(id='Active_teams_at_league_closing')
teams = heading.find_next('ul')
for team in teams:
    print(team.string)
```

Comment: hi there dear CDplayer and wpercy - many thanks for this great example - running v3 of python